# Refine gives strange results

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have

```
pr[x_] := PDF[PoissonDistribution[2], x]
```

and

```
Overage[x_] := Sum[(d - x)*pr[d], {d, x, Infinity}]
```

I would like to have Mathematica try simplify this. If not possible, it should at least keep it the same. However,

```
Refine[Overage[z], Assumptions -> z >= 0 && z \[Element] Integers]
```

yields errors "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." and "Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0 ComplexInfinity)/E^2 encountered.".

This is because it uses the gamma function at some point. I can even pinpoint the issue to `z==0`.

However, for z==0, the expression is just `Overage[0]` which is well-defined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @BobHanlon Even if d does not start at 0?

Comment: You can manually subtract the finite part, `Expectation[...] - Sum[..., {d, 0, x}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the warnings by using the following:

```
pr[x_] := Exp[-2] 2^x/x!
Overage[x_] := Sum[(d - x)*pr[d], {d, x, Infinity}]
f[z_] := Refine[Overage[z], 
  Assumptions -> z >= 0 && z \[Element] Integers]
f[z]
```

$$\frac{2^z \left(e^2 \left(-2^{-z}\right) z+e^2 2^{1-z}+\frac{2}{\Gamma (z+1)}+\frac{e^2 2^{-z} \Gamma (z+1,2)}{\Gamma (z)}-\frac{e^2 2^{1-z} \Gamma (z+1,2)}{\Gamma (z+1)}\right)}{e^2}$$

But if you can ignore the warnings and define

```
f[z_] := Refine[Overage[z], Assumptions -> z >= 0 && z \[Element] Integers]
```

then the function works as expected/desired

```
f[z]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{-2^{z+1} \Gamma (z)-2 e^2 \Gamma (z+1) \Gamma (z)+e^2 z \Gamma (z+1) \Gamma (z)+2 e^2 \Gamma (z) \Gamma (z+1,2)-e^2 \Gamma (z+1) \Gamma (z+1,2)}{e^2 \Gamma (z) \Gamma (z+1)} & z>0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

```
f[0]
(* 2 *)

f[3]
```

$$\frac{9-e^2}{e^2}$$

Comment: Thank you! Can I somehow eliminate the Gamma functions? If z is integer, I do not need it, I would suppose. But even without Gamma or !, the whole expression seems unnecessary complicated

Comment: Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.  You could replace the `Gamma[z]` values with `(z-1)!` using `f[z_] := Refine[Overage[z], 
   Assumptions -> z >= 0 && z \[Element] Integers] /. 
  Gamma[x_] -> (x - 1)!`.  There's not much of any simplification for the incomplete gamma: `Gamma[z+1,2]`.

Comment: I would prefer, though, to have my original `pr` function used instead of the clumsy long form

Comment: Then keep the original `pr` function.  As stated above all you have to do is ignore the warnings.  The original function performs fine.  It just gives some warnings. You can suppress the warnings by using the `Quiet` function.  (`Exp[-2] 2^x/x!` is a "clumsy long form" compared to `PDF[PoissonDistribution[2], x]` ??  I agree that using `PDF` is more natural and the desired function to use.

Comment: yes, `PDF` is easier to read, but also using my first `pr` function yields quite a messy expression because `PoissonDistribution` will be evaluated immediately